# InDesign CC File... but I am running CS5

Tags: adobe-indesign, cs5, cc-2014

I have inherited design files created in InDesign CC...but I am running CS5.  Other than the obvious solution of upgrading my software, are there any other resources that would allow me to work with this file?  I don't have any way of procuring the "exported" file format, which would possibly allow me to open this in a later version.  The .indd file is all I have. Thanks in advance for your help—I know this may be a long shot.  :-)

Comment: There is always  the "friend" resource...  Ask someone that has CC-2014 to save down.

Answer (score 2):

No.

There's no method to open newer InDesign files unless they have been *specifically* exported for backwards compatibility.

Of course.. there are always 30 day trials....

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Do you have an Adobe Account / Adobe ID Profile? If you have official software, when you installed(hopefully) you registered. If you are logged into adobe.com then when you try to open a newer file a Creative Cloud window will pop up and offer to convert for you.

I have to do this weekly. Note: I am using CS6, don't have CC, and it converts in a matter of seconds.

(It's been a couple of years since I installed, so I don't remember if logging into Adobe.com is sufficient, or if you have to go under the Help menu in ID, and click on Complete/Update Adobe ID Profile).

Yokel